# How to transform an array of objects into another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something",
    type: "free",
    id: "dsadsadada"
  },
  {
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something1",
    type: "premium",
    id: "fdss4a4654"
  }
]
```

and I would like to transform this array into this one:

```
const arr2 = [
    {
      date: "12-09-2018",
      data: [
        {
          type: "free",
          id: "dsadsadada",
          text: "something"
         },
         {
            type: "premium",
            id: "fdss4a4654",
            text: "something1"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

So in this case for each day I will have an array of data. What is the best approach ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `reduce`.

```js
const arr = [
    {
      date: "12-09-2018",
      text: "something",
      type: "free",
      id: "dsadsadada"
    },
    {
      date: "12-09-2018",
      text: "something1",
      type: "premium",
      id: "fdss4a4654"
    }
  ];

  const output = Object.values(arr.reduce((accu, {date, ...rest}) => {
    if(!accu[date]) {
        accu[date] = {date, data: []};
    }
    accu[date].data.push(rest);
    return accu;
  }, {}));

  console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your feedback I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const tempData = {};
 const arr = [
  {
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something",
    type: "free",
    id: "dsadsadada"
  },
  {
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something1",
    type: "premium",
    id: "fdss4a4654"
  }
]
arr.forEach(d=> {
if(!tempData[d.date]) tempData[d.date] = [];
const _data = {...d};
delete _data.date;
tempData[d.date].push(_data);
})
const arr2 = Object.keys(tempData).map(date=> {
  return {date, data: tempData[date]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `reduce` method of `Array` class, just like in the snippet

```js
const arr = [{
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something",
    type: "free",
    id: "dsadsadada"
  },
  {
    date: "12-09-2018",
    text: "something1",
    type: "premium",
    id: "fdss4a4654"
  }
]

const group = arr.reduce((arr, {
  date,
  ...value
}) => {
  let group = arr.find(grp => grp.date === date);
  if (!group) {
    group = {
      date,
      data: []
    }
    arr.push(group)
  }
  group.data.push(value)
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(group)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using a Map:

```
const dates = new Map();

arr.forEach(({ date, text, type, id}) => {

    if (dates.has(date)) {
        dates.set(date, [{ text, type, id}].concat(dates.get(date)))
    }
    else {
        dates.set(date, [{ text, type, id}])
    }
})
```